# How to configure filebeat to read log files from multiple linux servers

Tags: linux, logging, logstash, filebeat, elk

I need to know how to configure filebeat to read log files from multiple linux servers. I tried this for multiple windows computers and it works fine. Following is the used paths to access multiple log files from multiple windows computers in the network.

```
paths:
 - \\192.168.8.101\path\to\log\log.log
 - \\192.168.8.102\path\to\log\log.log
 - \\192.168.8.103\path\to\log\log.log
```

I want to do the same for multiple linux hosts. What is the recommended way to do that?

Comment: It is [not recommended](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-network-volumes.html) by elastic to read files from network volumes, but if you still want, on Linux you just need to mount the volumes on the filebeat machine and configure filebeat to read the directories.

Comment: Recommended to install filebeat on each server and configure it for the local path